# How to combine multiple Upper Bounds syntax with delegation syntax in Kotlin

Tags: generics, kotlin, delegation

Let's say I have the following interfaces:

```
interface A
interface B
interface C
```

I want to create class with multiple upper bounds for types A and B:

```
class First<T>(val t: T) where T : A, T : B
```

I also want to use delegation for type C:

```
class Second(val c: C) : C by c
```

My question is how do I combine both in one class declaration ?

I tried this:

```
class Third<T>(val t: T, val c: C) where T : A, T : B, C by c // syntax error: "Expecting : before the upper bound"
```

And this:

```
class Third<T>(val t: T, val c: C) : C by c where T : A, T : B // unresolved reference where
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The order of these two things can be figured out pretty quickly by looking at the [grammar for classes](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/grammar.html#classes), you'll see that delegation specifiers come before type constraints:

```
class 
  : modifiers ("class" | "interface") SimpleName
      typeParameters?
      primaryConstructor?
      (":" annotations delegationSpecifier{","})?
      typeConstraints
      (classBody? | enumClassBody)
  ;
```

Then it's just a matter of figuring out how to make these work in that order - it turns out that things get parsed correctly if you put the type constraints on a new line (as seen in the [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#upper-bounds) here and there):

```
class Third<T>(val t: T, val c: C) : C by c
        where T : A, T : B
```